# RichTextBox in WPF not resizing contents correctly

Tags: wpf, resize, richtextbox

I need to display text with colors and formatting in a `List`. I'm using a `ListBox` with a `RichTextControl` to display the data. I also need the contents to size to the window, but the text does not need to wrap.

When I make this simple example the text appears vertical and doesn't change as I size the window. If I set the `Width` of the `RichTextBox` to a fixed size like 100 then it works.

Any ideas?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication19.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <RichTextBox>
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run>this is a  test</Run>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
            </ListBox.Items>                
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If there is a better option for displaying text were parts of the text are different colors please let me know.

Comment: Do you need the ListBox so you can have selection etc, or are you using just to hold the ReichTextBox elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the list selection behaviour of the `ListBox`, then using a `ItemsControl` provides correct layout:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl>
        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph >
                    <Run>this is a  test</Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

The but to get what you asked for, wrap `RichTextBox` in the `Grid` and then Bind to it's `ActualWidth`

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <Grid>
                <RichTextBox Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" >
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run>this is a  test</Run>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
            </Grid>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Any idea why you need to set the width on the RichTextBox when it is inside a listbox item?

Comment: I am not sure what about the ListBox's interaction with the RichTextBox is causing this problem/requirement.

Comment: You can also use a ScrollViewer with a StackPanel in it, then just manage the children. This is what I ended up doing, but I prefer the ItemsControl solution you posted here.

Comment: An interesting issue I discovered with this:  If you set a margin on the RichTextBox, typing into it becomes extremely laggy, because it's calculating the actual width of the `Grid` and updating the `RichTextBox` with the new value at every keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the issue can be resolved by setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`. This has to do with `ListBox` using a `ScrollViewer` internally and how it interacts with `RichTextBox`.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <RichTextBox>
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>this is a  test</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```